# Minifying and combining files in .net

Tags: c#, javascript, css, minify

I am looking at implementing some performance optimization around my javascript/css. In particular looking to achieve the minification and combining of such. I am developing in .net/c# web applications.

I have a couple of options and looking for feedback on each:

First one is this clever tool I came across Chirpy which via visual studio combines, minifies etc -> http://chirpy.codeplex.com/ This is a visual studio add in but as I am in a team environment, this tool isnt ideal.

My next option is to use an Msbuild task (http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/) to minify the files and also combine them (maybe read from an xml file what needs to be combined). While this works for minifying fine, the concern I have is that I will have to maintain what must be combined which could be a headache.

3rd option is to use msbuild task just for the minifying and at runtime using some helper classes, combine the files on a per page basis. This would combine the files, give it a name and add a version to it.

Any other options I could consider? My concern with the last option is that it may have performance issues as I would have to open the file from the local drive, read its contents and then combine the files. This is alot of processing at run time. I was looking at something like Squishit - https://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt/downloads This minifies the files at run time but I would look at doing this at compile time.

So any feedback on my approaches would be great? If the 3rd option would not cause performance issues, I am leading towards it.

Comment: Maybe related http://stackoverflow.com/q/4234213/340760

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We have done something similar with several ASP.NET web applications.  Specifically, we use the [Yahoo Yui compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/), which has a .NET library version which you can reference in your applications.

The approach we took was to generate the necessary merged/minified files at runtime.  We wrapped all this logic up into an ASP.NET control, but that isn't necessary depending on your project.

- The first time a request is made for a page, we process through the list of included JS and CSS files.  In a separate thread (so the original request returns without delay) we then merged the included files together (1 for JS, 1 for CSS), and then apply the Yui compressor.
- The result is then written to disk for fast reference in the future
- On subsequent requests, the page first looks for the minified versions.  If found, it just serves those up.  If not, it goes through the process again.

As some icing to the cake:

- For debug purposes, if the query string ?debug=true is present, the merged/minified resources are ignored and the original individual files are served instead (since it can be hard to debug optimized JS)

We have found this process to work exceptionally well.  We built it into a library so all our ASP.NET sites can take advantage.  The post-build scripts can get complicated if each page has different dependencies, but the run-time can determine this quite easily.  And, if someone needs to make a quick fix to a CSS file, they can do so, delete the merged versions of the file, and the process will automatically start over without need to do post-build processing with MSBuild or NAnt.

Comment: Where can i obtain this wondrous magical machine/dll aka unicorn you speak of?
I wrote the exact same thing for coldfusion, and totally agree it works great. I was assuming such a thing would exist for .Net, but apparently not....

Answer (score 7):

[RequestReduce](http://www.RequestReduce.com) provides a really nice solution for combining and minifying javascript and css at run time. It will also attempt to sprite your background images. It caches the processed files and serves them using custom ETags and far future headers. [RequestReduce](http://www.RequestReduce.com) uses a response filter to transform the content so no code or configuration is needed for basic functionality. It can be configured to work in a web farm environment and sync content accross several servers and can be configured to point to a CDN. It can be downloaded at http://www.RequestReduce.com or from Visual Studio via Nuget. The source is available at https://github.com/mwrock/RequestReduce.

Comment: i've seen this answer in some other questions again by you. You must have it ready on your disk to copy paste it here :D nice library.  upvoted..

Answer (score 4):

have you heard of Combres ?
go to : http://combres.codeplex.com and check it out

it minifies your CSS and JS files at Runtime meaning you can change any file and upload it and each request the client does it minifies it.
all you gotta do is add the files u wanna compress to a list in the combres XML file and just call the list from your page / masterpage.

if you are using VS2010 you can easily install it on your project using NuGet
here's the Combres NuGet link: http://combres.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=5-Minute%20Quick%20Start

Comment: One of the best implementations I've used, great library.

Comment: +1 Nice. Very easy to use. Took about 15 minutes to set up in my project. Much simpler and more flexible than many other options.

Answer (score 2):

I did a really nice solution to this a couple of years back but I don't have the source left. The solution was for webforms but it should work fine to port it to MVC. I'll give it a try to explain what I did in some simple step. First we need to register the scripts and we wrote a special controller that did just that. When the controller was rendered it did three things:

1. Minimize all the files, I think we used the YUI compression
2. Combine all the files and store as string
3. Calculate a hash for the string of the combined files and use that as a virtual filename. You store the string of combined files in a cached dictionary on the server with the hash value as key, the html that is rendered needs to point to a special folder where the "scripts" are located.

The next step is to implement a special HttpHandler that handles request for files in the special folder. When a request is made to that special folder you make a lookup in the cached dictionary and returns the string bascially.

One really nice feature of this is that the returned script is always valid so the user will never have to ask you for an update of the script. The reason for that is when you make a change to any of the script files the hash value will change and the client will ask for a new script.

You can use this for css-files as well with no problems. I remebered making it configurable so you could turn off combine files, minimize files, or just exclude one file from the process if you wanted to do some debugging.

I might have missed some details, but it wasn't that hard to implement and it turned out very well.

**Update:** I've implemented a solution for MVC and released it on [nuget](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/SimpleCompression) and have the source up on [github](https://github.com/mastoj/SimpleCompression).

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft’s Ajax minifier](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/) is suprisingly good as a minification tool.  I wrote a blog post on combining files and using their minifier in a javascript and stylesheet handler:

http://www.markistaylor.com/javascript-concatenating-and-minifying/

Answer (score 0):

It's worthwhile combining the files at run time to avoid having to synchronise new versions. However, once they are programmatically combined, cache them to disk. Then the code which runs each time the files are fetched need only check that the files haven't changed before serving the cached version.

If they have changed, then the compression code can run as a one-off.
Whilst there will be a slight performance cost, you will also receive a performance benefit from fewer file requests.

This is the approach that the [Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) tool uses to compress JS/CSS, which has worked really well for me. It's Linux/PHP only, but you might get some more ideas there too.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a solution for combining/minifying CSS/JS on a .NET 2.0 web app and SquishIt and other tools I found weren't .NET 2.0-compatible, I created my own solution that uses a syntax similar to SquishIt but is compatible with .NET 2.0. Since I thought other people might find it useful I put it up on Github. You can find it here: https://github.com/AlliterativeAlice/simpleyui