# Is there a plugin which will automatically minify and cache JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, minify

I'm getting ready to start on a new project and I'd like to know if there's a way to automatically minify JavaScript on the server side, providing caching once the JavaScript has been minified once already? I could simply write a build script to accomplish this, but it'd be nice if I could "fire-and-forget" so to speak, with automatic minification. What would be the recommended route in this scenario? Should I minify my JavaScript before it goes online at the cost of time or should I look for something that'll automatically do it for me on the serverside?

#### EDIT

I'll probably be using Django, but of course, JavaScript and media is served separately from the actual "HTML"/application output.

Comment: This really depends on what server-sided framework you're using; you should probably specify.

Comment: Something automated. Otherwise it would be madness.

Comment: Put it in the build process. http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will all depend on what server side language you're using.  It will have nothing (so much) to do with Javascript or Css, but rather PHP, .NET, Ruby, etc.

(*note: these are just some quick searches I've done. I don't have any experience with any of them.*)

- PHP: [How to minify JS or CSS on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389822/how-to-minify-js-css-on-the-fly-runtime)
- .NET: [Minifying and combining files in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338570/minifying-and-combining-files-in-net)
- Ruby: [Juicer - a CSS and JavaScript packaging tool](http://cjohansen.no/en/ruby/juicer_a_css_and_javascript_packaging_tool)

I personally recommend **NOT** doing **ANY** of the minification / combining at run time since there is a server side performance hit that happens over and over and *over* again.

#### Above is my "Answer"

---

#### Below is my "Preference"

My preference is to use some sort of a Build Time minification / combining tool that achieves the goal once and leaves the server to just "serve".

*Since I'm running Visual Studio for my IDE, my preference is to use a tool called [Chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/)... the end result is a single static `site.min.js` file and a single static `site.min.css` file that has everything I need. I will no longer suffer a performance hit from combining/minifying my js/css at run time.*

---

#### Edit

Be sure to read the comments below, as they help add to the overall concept of what the OP is looking for.

---

#### Edit

Also just found [WebPutty](http://www.webputty.net/), looks like a pretty slick tool.

Comment: Definitely. I didn't know that there was something available like Chirpy to roll it all into one, so that's really cool. Hopefully if I roll something like YUI and `mod_deflate` or `mod_gzip` I'll get the best performance and file size.

Comment: However, are there any frameworks that minify __and__ cache JavaScript? (ie: first request causes the code to be minified and saved to a cache file, second request and on just pulls the cached file)

Comment: The best way to do the caching is to have a separate domain name, and have your web server do the caching. IIS and Apache both have ways of doing this. If you look at the StackOverflow source, you'll see that all static files come from `http://cdn.sstatic.net/` - It used to NOT be a cdn... and they were still able to get good cache performance out of `http://sstatic.net`.

Comment: just remember that the static domain has to be "Cookieless" which means it canNOT simply be a subdomain off of your existing domain.

Comment: As an extra tid bit of info, be sure to [SPRITE](http://spriteme.org/) your images to increase performance there too.

Comment: Here is some good information on cookieless domain performance: http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/static-cookieless-domain/

Comment: @rockinthesixstring in regard to hosting static content on a separate domain, do you have any suggestions for https sites/apps? How would that work?

Comment: @BZink. I'm a strong fan of [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/). Basically you sign up for a separate domain name and create a CName to point to your S3 bucket (they'll give you the domain name to use). You then send all your data from there, and can potentially have it as a CDN which will dramatically increase speed. I'm pretty sure that's what StackExchange is doing.

Answer (score 1):

[YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) works amazingly for me, requires Java on the server and you passing it the right params:

Here is my build script I use (written in Ruby, but does not have to), it calls the compressor with the right params, thats all it does.

```
#
# Build JS Files
#
require 'rake/packagetask'

JAVA = 'java'
OUTPUT = 'public/js/sitel-core.js'
MINOUTPUT = 'public/js/sitel-core.min.js'
OUTCSS = 'public/css/styles.css'
MINCSS = 'public/css/styles.min.css'
WIZOUT = 'public/js/sitel-wizard.js'
WIZMIN = 'public/js/sitel-wizard.min.js'

desc "Build CSS Scripts"
task :buildcss do
    files = 'public/css/styles.css'
    `#{JAVA} -jar build/yuicompressor.jar #{OUTCSS} -o #{MINCSS}`
end

desc "Build JS Scripts"
task :build => [:buildcss] do
    files = 'public/js/sitel.js public/js/sitel/popup.js public/js/microtable.js public/js/microbox.js public/js/sitel/popup.page.js public/js/sitel/flexigrid.js public/js/flexigrid/flexigrid.js public/js/nyroModal-1.6.2/js/jquery.nyroModal-1.6.2.js public/js/help-bubble.js public/js/sitel/elgg.js'
    `cat #{files} > #{OUTPUT}`
    `#{JAVA} -jar build/yuicompressor.jar #{OUTPUT} -o #{MINOUTPUT}`    

    wizard = 'public/js/wizard2.js public/js/dual-select.js public/js/filterbox.js public/js/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.js public/js/smartsearch.js public/js/smartsearch-validator.js public/js/flexigrid/flexigrid_helper.js '
    `cat #{wizard} > #{WIZOUT}`
    `#{JAVA} -jar build/yuicompressor.jar #{WIZOUT} -o #{WIZMIN}`
end

desc "Build JS Scripts"
task :default => :build
```

Comment: YUI is the "standard" compressor that I think most other apps run on. I know that Chirpy uses YUI beneath the sheets.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Apache you can use this solution that serve minified js files on the fly :
https://www.unixmen.com/how-to-auto-minify-javascript-files-on-page-load-in-apache-using-uglifyjs/

Comment: There is also an nginx module for it as well: https://github.com/nginx-modules/nginx-minify