# MVC Mini Profiler Exception on MiniProfiler.Stop()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm just added Mini Profiler to my MVC3 project with nuget and I've followed the basic steps to get it set up. Starting the profile on Application_BeginRequest() and stopping it on Application_EndRequest()

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        if (Request.IsLocal)
        {
            MiniProfiler.Start();
        }

    }

    protected void Application_EndRequest()
    {
        MiniProfiler.Stop();
    }
```

MiniProfiler.Stop() is throwing an exception - **"Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent."**

Has anybody else seen this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be related to Combres (http://combres.codeplex.com/). If I ignore the requests for my js and css that has been combined and compressed with combres the profiler seems to work better (no exception being thrown)

Comment: Can I just say that Combres (though a well built tool) is probably not something that you want to use. If you're looking to combine and minify your css/js, you should do it at build time in order to lessen server load. [Here's another post I wrote on the subject.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687475/is-there-a-plugin-which-will-automatically-minify-and-cache-javascript/6687530#6687530)

Comment: Note: the main point in that topic is that you should use [Chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/) for combining and minifying your JS/CSS - It's a FANTASTIC tool... and no, I don't have any affiliation with them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll look at Chirpy. Combres was the best thing I could find at the time I was looking, it does seem rather "heavy" though at run time.

Comment: Chirpy does the work while your designing, so you can put a static file up to the server that is already combined and minified. The config options are really sweet, and I absolutely love the fact that it has .LESS support.

Answer (score 7):

Old question but answering anyway.

Problem caused by some component (`SignalR` in my case) calls `HttpResponse.Flush`.
Solved by excluding `SignalR` from profiling. Below is a simple version of what we have done.

```
if (Request.IsLocal && !Request.Path.StartsWith("/signalr"))
{
    MiniProfiler.Start();
}
```

Hope it helps.